# .NET API POST endpoint returns inconsistent status codes for exact same request data

Tags: c#, .net, api, post, smartystreets

I have an API (let's call it API#1) that I've been able to test via localhost w/ swagger and indirectly through our application's site (QA version). With the EXACT same posted values, I am sometimes getting a 500 error, and sometimes a 200 OK response in both localhost and live on our QA site.

API#1 calls a geolocation service api, which then calls a smartystreets endpoint to get Lat/Long coordinates from a given zip code. I've tested the geolocation api with the same zip code value and it always returns 200. So the issue lies somewhere in API#1.

When it performs the exact same call from API#1 through the geolocation api to smartystreets, it sometimes returns NotFound, and sometimes returns the correct lat/long coordinates. NotFound will throw a 500 error in API#1.

I am wondering if this is a CORS issue in API#1, but then again, the results are very inconsistent.

Localhost site in Browser calling API#1:

[image: Live in Browser]

Calling the API via LocalHost/Swagger:
[image: Calling the API via LocalHost]

Comment: content-type, headers, and https .. ensure they're all have been set correctly. Also, use `Fiddler` to track the requests/responses and you can inspect them to see what causes this issue.

Comment: Trying to troubleshoot three different APIs at the same time as they interact with each other introduces a lot of extra variables. I suggest making requests to each API individually to see how each one responds.